# Change the plot marker

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

Here is a sample code which plots two points

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = Point[1.45 ({Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ {-Pi/2 + 1/2, 3 Pi/2 - 1/2})];
Graphics[pts]
```

This code is just a small part of a larger code, so its main structure and purpose should be remain the same. What I want is to change the plot marker so instead of two dots to print another symbol, let's say two five-pointed filled stars.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use ‘ListPlot’ with option ‘PlotMarker’

Comment: `text = Text["\[FivePointedStar]", 1.45 {Cos@#, Sin@#}] & /@ {-Pi/2 + 
     1/2, 3 Pi/2 - 1/2}; Graphics[text]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `Graphics` and `Text`:**

```
text = Text[Style["\[FivePointedStar]", 32, Red], 1.45 {Cos@#, Sin@#}] & /@ 
  {-Pi/2 + 1/2, 3 Pi/2 - 1/2};
Graphics[text, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> (1.45 Through@{Cos, Sin}@{-Pi/2 + 1/2, 3 Pi/2 - 1/2})]
```

[image]

**Using `ListPlot` and `PlotMarkers`:**

```
ListPlot[1.45 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ {-Pi/2 + 1/2, 3 Pi/2 - 1/2}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FivePointedStar]", Red, 32], 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Ticks -> (1.45 Through@{Cos, Sin}@{-Pi/2 + 1/2, 3 Pi/2 - 1/2})]
```

[image]